# list index out of range - beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

NEW TO PYTHON*** Below is my code I am using to pull a zip file from a website but I am getting the error, "list index out of range". I was given this code by someone else who wrote it but I had to change the URL and now I am getting the error. When I print(list_of_documents) it is blank.

Can someone help me with this? The url requires access so you won't be able to try to input this code directly. I am trying to understand how to use beautiful soup in this and how I can get the list to populate correctly.

```
import datetime
import requests
import csv
from zipfile import ZipFile as zf
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyodbc
import re

#set download location

downloads_folder = r"C:\Scripts\"


##### Creating outage dataframe

#Get list of download links

res = requests.get('https://www.ercot.com/mp/data-products/data-product-details?id=NP3-233-CD')

ercot_soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

list_of_documents = ercot_soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'labelOptional_ind'})
list_of_links = ercot_soup.select('a')'

##create the url for the download 

loc = str(list_of_links[0])[9:len(str(list_of_links[0]))-9]
link = 'http://www.ercot.com' + loc
link = link.replace('amp;','')

# Define file name and set download path

file_name = str(list_of_documents[0])[30:len(str(list_of_documents[0]))-5]
file_path = downloads_folder + '/' + file_name
```

Comment: can you put the output your answer?

Comment: The site throws 403 `access denied` error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KaliMachine Do you mean to show the error I get?

Comment: @Nicole_abdul what are you trying to get with `labelOptional_ind` ? I don't see that when inspecting the page.

Comment: @Driftr95 that was there from the other person that created the original code using URL https://www.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=13103.

Comment: @Driftr95 I believe that is the part that is wrong but I am not sure what to change it to. I've never used Beautiful Soup so this is new to me.

Comment: @Nicole_abdul the list looks the same as far as I can see, and the source is the same. Why do you need to get it from this specific path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect code tailored to scrape one website to work for a different link! You should always [inspect](https://www.thedataschool.co.uk/conrad-wilson/scraping-a-web-page-part-1-inspecting-the-html) and explore your target site, especially the parts you need to scrape, so you know the tag names [like `td` and `a` here] and identifying attributes [like `name`, `id`, `class`, etc.] of the elements you need to extract data from.

With this site, if you want the info from the `reportTable`, it gets generated after the page gets loaded with javascript, so it wouldn't show up in the `request` response. You could either try something like [Selenium](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/), or you could try retrieving the data from the source itself.

If you [inspect the site and look at the network tab](https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020623654-How-do-I-use-the-Network-view-in-Dev-Tools-), you'll find a request (which is what actually retrieves the data for the table) that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsYpv.png), and when you [inspect the table's html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnBL4.png), you'll find above it the scripts to generate the data.

In the suggested solution below, the `getReqUrl` scrapes your link to get the url for requesting the reports (and also the template of the url for downloading the documents).

```
def getReqUrl(scrapeUrl):
  res = requests.get(scrapeUrl)
  ercot_soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

  script = [l.split('"') for l in [
      s for s in ercot_soup.select('script')
      if 'reportListUrl' in  s.text 
      and 'reportTypeID' in s.text
  ][0].text.split('\n') if l.count('"') == 2]

  rtID = [l[1] for l in script if 'reportTypeID' in l[0]][0]
  rlUrl = [l[1] for l in script if 'reportListUrl' in l[0]][0]
  rdUrl = [l[1] for l in script if 'reportDownloadUrl' in l[0]][0]

  return f'{rlUrl}{rtID}&_={int(time.time())}', rdUrl
```

(I couldn't figure out how to scrape the last query parameter [the `&_=...` part] from the site exactly, but `{int(time.time())}}` seems to get close enough - the results are the same even then and even when that last bit is omitted entirely; so it's totally optional.)

The url returned can be used to request the documents:

```
#import json

url = 'https://www.ercot.com/mp/data-products/data-product-details?id=NP3-233-CD'
reqUrl, ddUrl = getReqUrl(url)
reqRes = requests.get(reqUrl[0]).text
rsJson = json.loads(reqRes)

for doc in rsJson['ListDocsByRptTypeRes']['DocumentList']:
  d = doc['Document'] 
  downloadLink = ddUrl+d['DocID']
  #print(f"{d['FriendlyName']} {d['PublishDate']} {downloadLink}")
  print(f"Download '{d['ConstructedName']}' at\n\t {downloadLink}")
print(len(rsJson['ListDocsByRptTypeRes']['DocumentList']))
```

The `print` results will look like [image]